# python equal strings are not equal with new line character in it

Tags: python, dictionary, passwords, newline, special-characters

I have a password. It contains newline (lets for now omit why) character and is:
**"h2sdf\ndfGd"**
This password is in dict **my_dict**. When I just print values of dict I get "\" instead of "" - **"h2sdf\ndfGd"**! Don't understand why.
When I get it and use it to authenticate to web server, it says that Authentication fails. When I try to compare:

```
my_dict["password"] == "h2sdf\ndfGd"
```

it returns **False**.

But when I try just **print(my_dict["password"])** I get **h2sdf\ndfGd** which is identical, but for python it is not. Why? I am lost.

Comment: You need to escape the ``\`` character: ``my_dict["password"] == "h2sdf\\ndfGd"``

Comment: My question is why dict returns \\ instead of \, and my password fails, because I believe python library somehow uses \\ instead of \

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
>>> print("h2sdf\ndfGd")
h2sdf
dfGd
>>> print("h2sdf\\ndfGd")
h2sdf\ndfGd
```

You simply have to escape `\n` with a double `\` backslash, to prevent it to become a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Characters like tabs, newlines, which cannot be represented in a string are described using an escape sequence with a backslash.

In order to indicate that the backslash is not part of an escape sequence(`\n`, `\t`, ...), it must itself be escaped using another backslash: `\\`.

```
my_dict["password"] == "h2sdf\\ndfGd"
```

If you don't want to have to escape all your `\`, you can use a raw string instead.

Raw strings are prefixed with `r` or `R`, and treat backslashes `\` as literal characters.

```
my_dict["password"] == r"h2sdf\ndfGd"
```

Comment: Question is why dict returns // instead of /. How can I make dict return raw string, not escaped?